# IOS expo-camera preview remains black screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

**Expected Behavior** : In IOS StandAlone app making expo-camera preview not black screen.

**Some things to add**: I have in app.json the infoPlist the NSCameraUsageDescription-
I ask the user to allow the use of camera, when this pops the screen is blank and when he accepts the preview remains black
When testing this on Dev ( expo app ) it works perfectly
When testing on expo build and open the app on expo app it works too
when i eas build and sent do app store connect , in testflight or in standalone app it doesnt work!

**expo-camera version** : "expo-camera": "~12.2.0",

**Example**

```
return (
{previewVisible && capturedImage ? (

) : (
<Camera style={styles.camera}
type={type}
ref={camera}
flashMode={'auto'}
whiteBalance={"sunny"}

        >
            <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column', justifyContent: 'flex-end' }} >
                <LinearGradient style={[{ padding: 15, elevation: 10, paddingBottom: 25 }]} colors={['transparent', 'black']}>
                    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between' }} >
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={voltarEcraAnterior} style={[styles.previewButtons, styles.circle]}>
                            <Icon name="icon-cross" style={styles.iconButtonsCamera} size={40}></Icon>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={takePicture} style={[styles.previewButtons, styles.circle,]}>
                            <Icon name="icon-scan" style={styles.iconButtonsCamera} size={40}></Icon>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                </LinearGradient>
            </View>
        </Camera>
    )
    }
</View >
);
```

**Permissions**

```
const __startCamera = async () => {
    const { status } = await Camera.requestCameraPermissionsAsync();
    setHasPermission(status === 'granted');
}
```

Comment: Hi! Have you fixed this? I'm having the exact same issue.

Comment: yes i did, please do check the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After months and months i managed to fix this issue, all you have to do :

- Update SDK to Expo 47.
- Update expo-camera to 13.1.0.